# Read a .CSV file and insert it into SQL SERVER - something is missing

Tags: csv, sql-server-2012, vb6

I have a function that looks as such...

```
Dim iFileNo As Integer
Dim sLine As String
Dim sSQL_InsertPrefix As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim vasFields As Variant
Dim iIndex As Long


iFileNo = FreeFile
'Open File
Open FileName For Input As #iFileNo

If EOF(iFileNo) Then
    Exit Sub
End If

sSQL_InsertPrefix = "INSERT INTO temptable (Vendor, Invoice, Date1, Date2, HoldPayment, NetRedeemed, GlCode, ServiceName, SepCheck) VALUES ("

Do Until EOF(iFileNo)
    Line Input #iFileNo, sLine

    'Initialize SQL STRING
    sSQL = sSQL_InsertPrefix

    vasFields = Split(sLine, " , ")

    For iIndex = 0 To UBound(vasFields) - 1
        sSQL = sSQL & "'"
        sSQL = sSQL & vasFields(iIndex)
        sSQL = sSQL & "'"
        sSQL = sSQL & ","
    Next iIndex

    sSQL = sSQL & "'"
    sSQL = sSQL & vasFields(iIndex)
    sSQL = sSQL & "'"

    sSQL = sSQL & ")"

    g_cn.Execute sSQL
Loop

Close #iFileNo
```

Everything looks okay as in, the file gets opened, I am able to go into the file, it recognizes the data in my .csv files in this line

```
Line Input #iFileNo, sLine
```

However, when it gets to

```
vasFields = Split(sline," , ")
```

VasFields it not being split

so when it gets to the loop :

```
For iIndex = 0 to Ubound(vasFields) - 1
```

it skips right to the end and instead hits this part

```
    sSQL = sSQL & "'"
    sSQL = sSQL & vasFields(iIndex)
    sSQL = sSQL & "'"

    sSQL = sSQL & ")"
```

So the whole VALUES part of the insert statement, only gets the single quotes in the beginning and end. Overall abbreviated insert statement looks like this..

```
Insert into temptable (x, y, z) Values ('123,XXX,456') <-- in which case it treats it as a single value aI believe and gives me an error that the number of insert field has to be equal to specified values
```

Any idea why vasFields=split(sline," , ") is not getting the values?

Comment: Are you sure there is a space before and after the comma delimiters?  If not, I'd remove the spaces from the second parameter for the split function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the literal being used in the second parameter of the split function.  It's looking for exactly a space-comma-space combination.  I'd take out the spaces and try this instead:

```
vasFields = Split(sline,",")
```